# Setting TimeOut for a page inside an iframe

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have recently see this piece of code where i can set the request time out for a specific page inside web.config my question is if the page is being loaded inside an iframe do the web.config still know that the request is for that page not the parent page ?

```
<location path="Partners/GetPartners.aspx">
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
</location>
```

GetPartners.aspx is being load from an iframe inside a page called showPartners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because in that iframe it will be loaded with its own request.